# How to change the picture while clicking on element. It must only show then pictures with one size, not other sizes.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I have got a problem that I cannot fix... 
How to change the size of grinder (only the picture) while clicking on 15CM (p element). Normal size is 24CM (class highlighted). When I click on the square color it changes the grinder color (but only the 24CM grinder uusing attribute: data-img-k). I would like to also change the size of grinder when I click on 15CM. Then it should change the picture for 15cm grinder with data attribute: data-img-k15. And then it should only changing the colors (pictures) of 15cm grinders until somebody will click other size.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.product-color').click(function () {


        var codek = $(this).data('code-k');
        var namek = $(this).data('name-k');
        var imgk = $(this).data('img-k');

        $('#grinder-code-k').text(codek);
        $('#grinder-name-k').text(namek);
        $('#grinder-photo-k').attr('src', imgk);


    });
});
```

```css
.grinder-wrapper {
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.product-photo {
  height: 600px;
}


/*Kolumna 1*/

.grinder-wrapper>div {
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.grinder-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}

.grinder-wrapper>div:first-child {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.model {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  top: 1em;
  z-index: 999;
}


/*Kolumna 2*/

.product-color-outer {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-color-box {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.product-color-box p {
  margin: 0;
}

.product-color {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-box-up-and-down {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 0 0 3em;
}

.product-box-down {
  height: 300px;
}


/*Kolumna 3*/

.product-info-outer {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-box-up {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.product-box-up p {
  text-align: center;
}

#grinder-code>span,
#grinder-name>span {
  color: #3476bd;
}


/*Border effect wewnątrz*/

.product-color-outer:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  right: 0;
}

.product-color-outer:before {
  content: '';
  height: 90%;
  width: 2px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  right: 0;
}

.product-info-outer:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  left: -3em;
}

.product-box-down-line {
  position: relative;
}

.product-box-down p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3476bd;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

.highlighted{
    background-color:  #f4f4f4;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    color: #888;
    margin-right: 1em;
     color: #111;
     cursor: pointer;
}
.not-highlighted{
    background-color:  #f4f4f4;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    color:  #cbcbcb;
    margin-right: 1em;
     cursor: pointer;
}

/*Kolory tradycyjne*/
.white{
    background: #fff;
}
.black{
    background: #000;
}
.cream{
    background: #f4f2db;
}
.wenge{
    background: #432214;
}
```

```html
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper grinder-wrapper">

  <!--First column-->
  <div class="product-photo">
    <h3 class="model">Model klasyczny</h3>
    <img id="grinder-photo-k" src="http://blosiu.webd.pl/młynki/img/grinders/klasyczny/klasyczny11.png" alt="młynek do mielenia" width="350">
  </div>

  <!--Second column-->
  <div class="product-box-up-and-down">
    <div class="product-color-outer">
      <h4>Kolory<span class="available">dostępne</span></h4>
      <p>Tradycyjne</p>
      <div class="product-color-box">
        <p class="product-color white" data-code-k="W-PR-15-MM" data-name-k="młynek klasyczny, kolor biały, wysokość 24cm, mechanizm metalowy" data-img-k="http://blosiu.webd.pl/młynki/img/grinders/klasyczny/klasyczny1.png"
        data-img-k15="http://blosiu.webd.pl/m%C5%82ynki/img/grinders/klasyczny15/klasyczny1.png">
        </p>
        <p class="product-color black" data-code-k="SW-PR-15-MM" data-name-k="młynek klasyczny, kolor czarny, wysokość 24cm, mechanizm metalowy" data-img-k="http://blosiu.webd.pl/młynki/img/grinders/klasyczny/klasyczny2.png"
        data-img-k15="http://blosiu.webd.pl/m%C5%82ynki/img/grinders/klasyczny15/klasyczny2.png">
        </p>
        <p class="product-color cream" data-code-k="KS-PR-15-MM" data-name-k="młynek klasyczny, kolor kremowy, wysokość 24cm, mechanizm metalowy" data-img-k="http://blosiu.webd.pl/młynki/img/grinders/klasyczny/klasyczny3.png"
        data-img-k15="http://blosiu.webd.pl/m%C5%82ynki/img/grinders/klasyczny15/klasyczny3.png">
        </p>
        <p class="product-color wenge" data-code-k="WG-PR-15-MM-3" data-name-k="młynek klasyczny, kolor wenge, wysokość 24cm, mechanizm metalowy" data-img-k="http://blosiu.webd.pl/młynki/img/grinders/klasyczny/klasyczny4.png"
        data-img-k15="http://blosiu.webd.pl/m%C5%82ynki/img/grinders/klasyczny15/klasyczny4.png">
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!--Third columnt-->
  <div class="product-box-up-and-down">
    <div class="product-info-outer">
      <h4>Wysokości<span class="available">dostępne</span></h4>
      <div class="product-box-up">
        <div>
          <p class="not-highlighted klasyczny-15" data-k15="img/grinders/klasyczny15/klasyczny1.png">15<br> CM
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="not-highlighted">18<br> CM
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="highlighted">24<br> CM
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="not-highlighted">32<br> CM
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-box-down product-box-down-line">
      <h4>Informacje</h4>
      <p>Kod produktu: <span id="grinder-code-k">WG-PR-15-MM-3 </span></p>
      <p>Nazwa produktu: <span id="grinder-name-k">młynek klasyczny, kolor wenge, wysokość 24cm, mechanizm metalowy</span></p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--End of wrapper-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new boolean to your JS which would toggle whenever the size is changed. In your document.ready before the click method, you can add: `var currentSize = '24CM';`

Then, on each of the clicks you can check whether the size is 24 or 15, and use that particular data attribute accordingly:

```
$('.product-color').click(function () {
    var codek = $(this).data('code-k');
    var namek = $(this).data('name-k');
    var imgk = $(this).data('img-k');

    if (currentSize === '15CM') imgk = $(this).data('img-k15');
    //you can add as many cases for all sizes here as needed.

    $('#grinder-code-k').text(codek);
    $('#grinder-name-k').text(namek);
    $('#grinder-photo-k').attr('src', imgk);
});
```

now for the size click, i'd probably add a different class to these and also add the size into some new data attribute:

```
<div class="product-box-up size-select-container">
    <div>
      <p class="not-highlighted klasyczny-15" data-size-select="15CM">15<br> CM
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="not-highlighted" data-size-select="18CM">18<br> CM
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="highlighted" data-size-select="24CM">24<br> CM
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="not-highlighted" data-size-select="32CM">32<br> CM
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now that you have this class, use it to apply a click:

```
$('.size-select-container p').click(function() {
    //remove highlighted class from all sizes
    $('.size-select-container p').removeClass('highlighted');
    $('.size-select-container p').addClass('not-highlighted');
    //add highlighted class to the one you selected:
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
    //now set the currentSize variable based on what is selected:
    currentSize = $(this).data('size-select');
});
```

Since this has set the new currentSize variable, you will now be able to stay viewing images of the most recent size selected until that size is changed.

Comment: You are the master!!! Thenk you a lot. I would like to buy you a beer someday :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have got one more small obstacle. How to automatically change the picture when click on ('.size-select-container p') with the same color of grinder? Now I must click on p element first and then again on the same color to change the picture for smaller grinder. It looks simple, but it isn't for me :-)